# Only Insert Into a table if a value is unique on a non-unique row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying this sqlite query on an existing database and table:

```
INSERT INTO Actions (guide_id, user_id, action_type, action_date, article_id,  guide_name) VALUES (33, 1199180, 2, 1355829894, 2457, 'Amsterdam');
```

This works, but if I run the same thing again it will insert duplicate values which is not wanted.

This is how the table looks like:

[image: A description of the Table]

The problem here is that article_id is not unique.
I want the insert only to run when article_id does not exists in the column.

In theory I want something like:

```
IF x DOES NOT EXISTS IN article_id DO (INSERT INTO Actions (guide_id, user_id, action_type, action_date, article_id,  guide_name) VALUES (33, 1199180, 2, 1355829894, 2457, 'Amsterdam'));
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
INSERT INTO Actions (guide_id, user_id, action_type, action_date, article_id,  guide_name)
VALUES (33, 1199180, 2, 1355829894, 2457, 'Amsterdam') WHERE NOT article_id = x;
```

Another way would be to define the `article_id` as a `UNIQUE` key:

```
create unique index unique_name on Actions (article_id );
```

You can find more information at [the sqlite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints).

Comment: Can I ALTER article_id to be unique without removing the table or creating another table?

Comment: sure you can, try `create unique index unique_name on Actions (article_id );`

Comment: The create unique index does not actually alter the table, but it creates an index. Is there a way to alter the table to make article_id unique?

Comment: Never mind, I think I misunderstood how index works. I created an index and put a INSERT OR IGNORE INTO at the beginning of the insert statement. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_duplicates_articles
AFTER INSERT ON Article
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Article 
   WHERE action_date NOT IN (SELECT MIN(action_date) 
                             FROM Article 
                             WHERE article_id = new.article_id)
   AND article_id = new.article_id;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want article_id to be unique, then article_id should be the primary key, not action_id.

Comment: The effects in restricting to uniqueness are the same, but `UNIQUE` is not the same as `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you add a `UNIQUE` constraint?

```
ALTER TABLE Actions
ADD UNIQUE (article_id);
```

Comment: This does not work since you can not alter a column in SqLite. At least not that I'm aware of.